# blowing up the slash on arrows in xy-pic

Tags: xy-pic

I have a large diagram of dependencies that I want to put in a math paper.  I want some of the arrows to denote implication, and I want crossed-out arrows to denote specific non-implications.  Here's a small part of it.

```
\xymatrix{
& \txt{Dedekind} \ar@2[dl] \ar@2[dr]|{\object@{/}}\\
\txt{Noetherian\\ normal} & & \txt{globally\\ perinormal}
}
```

The little portion of my chart above means that every Dedekind domain is Noetherian normal, but that there *exist* Dedekind domains that are *not* globally perinormal.  However, the cross-out slash of the arrow, when done this way, is rather small.  I'm worried that a casual reader would think the slash is a mistake, and that I actually mean that all Dedekind domains *are* globally perinormal.

How do I make the slash a lot bigger?  Is this even possible with Xy-pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I recommend to use [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd) for this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{degil/.style={
        decoration={markings,
            mark= at position 0.5 with {
                \node[transform shape] (tempnode) {$\backslash$};}},
        postaction={decorate}}}
\newcommand{\textCDedge}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}} % you may switch to 'l' or alike later, if you do not like the centred alignment anymore

\begin{document}
\[  
\xymatrix{ & \txt{Dedekind} \ar@2[dl] \ar@2[dr]|{\object@{/}}\\ \txt{Noetherian\\ normal} & & \txt{globally\\ perinormal} }
\]  
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[arrows=Rightarrow]
& \textCDedge{Dedekind} \ar{dl} \ar[degil]{dr}&\\
\textCDedge{Noetherian \\ normal}&& \textCDedge{globally\\perinormal}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The package is much more modern, powerful and easier to read. It would be easy to rewrite your existing diagram as the `\ar` can be used in both packages and you could redefine `\txt` to my definition of `\textCDedge`.

Comment: Thank you!  And by the way, if I wanted to put labels above the arrows, how would I do that?

Comment: @neil sorry, I am on a mobile. Please see any post tagged as [tag:tikz-cd] or read the manual. It's really easy.